# chat search schema design

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, schema, database-schema

I have to design a chat search capability on my chat software. The chat software allows the user to talk to users/channels inside the same company. I want to build a chat search functionality for users to whom he had chats or channels to which he is a member.

I am aware of ElasticSearch which is good for doing some global searches (irrespective of user's context) but in chat application the search is always limited to chats of the user who is performing the search. That is, if I am searching for 'hello' no need to search for all the 'hello' sent by other users or to channels to which I am not a member.

Can someone suggest some docs/reference/technologies to be used to power this feature? Also what might be the possible schema design so that it is very fast.

Comment: check this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/faking-it.html

Comment: This won't work. At the end it is a big shared index. I don't want to search for chat texts which is relevant to other company/user/channels in which user is not part of. And this can be huge impact on performance and latency.